# Highcharts with PHP var

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, highcharts

I am novice with JavaScript, and in my website I need to use highchart with some PHP var. And I have a question :
With Highchart, I need to complete some information :

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},
```

I have my array in PHP coverted in JavaScript with :

```
var array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

But, the length of my array is never the same length between differents users. And I need to complete "categories" with all the values in my array.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why the length is different? Maybe you have morE data per-month and just need to decide how use it (e.g.: calculate average per-month). Please, give more details..

Comment: I don't need to enter the array data linked to a mounth, I need to enter each data in the "categories". (ex : $array = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), so I want to have : categories: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My actual code is the following :

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [<?php foreach($array as $value) {
        echo "'".$value."', ";
    }?>]
},
```

But it doesn't work, because the graph don't appear. :/

EDIT : Solution is :

```
var array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

And then

```
xAxis: {
    categories: array 
},
```

Comment: This highlights the importance of being clear in your question, and providing code examples. :)

Answer (score 1):

The categories will only show on the chart if there is also data for them in the series.  For instance, if you supply 4 categories, but only 3 data points, only 3 categories will display.

If you want to show 4 categories, but you only have 3 data points currently, you can set the 4th data point to 0 or null, and the 4th category will display.

If this doesn't answer your question you'll need to be more specific and provide a fiddle or live example.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is : I don't understand how to do a loop to complete the JavaScript array. :/

Comment: It will depend a lot on what your arrays look like.  If you can provide an example of both your categories array, and your data array, we can provide more specific help.  What you're doing to build the categories array is correct - the only reason I can see that it wouldn't display as desired is that your data array doesn't match.

Comment: The PHP array can contain : Unranked, Unranked3x3, OdinUnranked , AramUnranked5x5, CoopVsAI, CoopVsAI3x3, RankedSolo5x5, RankedTeam3x3, RankedTeam5x5, OneForAll5x5, FirstBlood1x1, FirstBlood2x2, SummonersRift6x6, CAP5x5, URF, URFBots. But it's possible to see this array with only 6 or 7 values.

Comment: Ok, that appears to be the categories.  But what's you actual data look like?  I think you need to post your chart code, and your php that you build the data with...